# How are Component.process*Event methods supposed to be used in swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, mouse

This example has a `JPanel` that overrides `processMouseMotionEvent` and `processKeyEvent`, but these methods are not invoked at all when the panel is interacted with. What is the utility of these methods? How are they supposed to be used:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class T extends JPanel {
    T() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var f = new JFrame("T");
        f.setSize(100, 100);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new T());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The processMouseMotionEvent and processKeyEvent methods are defined in the JComponent class.  The methods do what they say, they allow you to process a mouse motion event and a key event.  I couldn't find any code examples using these methods.

Comment: I copied the code into Eclipse.  Using Java 8 and running the code on Java JDK 13.0.2, I couldn't get either process method to respond.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That is the issue. Why don't they work?

Comment: I've never used these methods.  I never knew about these methods until today.  @camickr's answer is how I've always dealt with event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the utility of these methods? How are they supposed to be used:

There is no need for you to worry about those methods or override those methods.

The methods will be invoked when you add listeners to the component:

```
    T t = new T();
    t.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    });
```

So again there is no need to override them.

You add your logic to the listener code. Listeners allow you to add functionality without overriding methods in your class and the listener can potentially be reused with multiple classes.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" this answer (and others you have asked) by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.